# SQL If data not found in similar date, get last date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table `[Price]` like this

> Date Item Price
>
> ```
> 1-1-2012 Potion 500
> 1-1-2012 Elixir 5000
> 1-10-2012 Potion 600
> ```

Table `[Transaction]`

> Date Item Amount
>
> 1-1-2012 Potion 1
>       1-5-2012 Potion 1

I need to join these tables, with the price and transaction side by side. The rule is if the date is not found in [Price], use latest price

So, 1-5-2012 Potion will cost 500

The result should be like this

> Date Item Amount Price
>
> 1-1-2012 Potion 1 500
>       1-5-2012 Potion 1 500

So, I don't know how to do this, please help if you know the solution.
Thanks

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, thanks for the reply

Comment: do you have primary keys not shown here?

Comment: Thanks for commenting Luis Siquot, but there is no primary key and I've got my answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple SCALAR SUBQUERY will do.

```
select t.date, t.item, t.amount,
       (select top(1) price
          from price
         where t.item=p.item and p.date <= t.date
      order by p.date desc) price
  from [transaction] t;
```

Comment: Thanks, RichardTheKiwi, I've tried this and this is the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 SELECT 
    t.Date, 
    t.Item, 
    t.Amount,
    ISNULL(
       p.Price, 
       (
          SELECT TOP 1 p1.Price FROM [Price] p1 
          WHERE p1.Item = t.Item 
          ORDER BY Date DESC
       ) [Price]
 FROM 
     [Transaction] t 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
         [Price] p
         ON 
         t.Date = p.Date
         AND
         t.Item = p.Item
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it still not right, I use another subset and the solution is not right for that subset, but anyway thank you for answering